# Scanning switch interfaces

Tags: switch

So i have nine 3com 4500G 24-port switches and i need a way to scan the interfaces on the switches and tell me info on the devices connected to them (EG: ip, mac, hostname) is there any such way to do this on 3com switches or from a client pc ?

I have tried Spiceworks, Nagios and Nmap but cant get any of them to work the way i want them to.

As a side note the reason I need to do this is the switches in question aren't counting traffic properly, there is a PC on the interface below that is used daily but the count shows no traffic.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
 port: GigabitEthernet1/0/2

 Input (total):  0 packets, 0 bytes
     0 broadcasts, 0 multicasts
 Input (normal):  - packets, - bytes
     - broadcasts, - multicasts
 Input:  0 input errors, 0 runts, 0 giants, - throttles
     0 CRC, - frame, - overruns, 0 aborts
     - ignored, - parity errors
 Output (total): 0 packets, 0 bytes
     0 broadcasts, 0 multicasts, 0 pauses
 Output (normal): - packets, - bytes
     - broadcasts, - multicasts, - pauses
 Output: 0 output errors, - underruns, - buffer failures
     0 aborts, 0 deferred, 0 collisions, 0 late collisions
     0 lost carrier, - no carrier
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only information that the switch is going to collect on particular machines is the MAC address - either via the bridge table layer2 or the arp table layer 3.

Is the switch in question part of a "stack"? I know there is a way of stacking these switches with a proprietary 10 Gig connection (I think they call it a CX4 connector) to create one logical switch out of a stack with a master/subordinate relationship between them. Could it be that the data you are looking for is only accessible via the master switch in the stack?

Comment: They are in a "stack" but the "count" for the individual switches are only available on the switches them selfies, so if the switch only collects MAC addresses is there a way of getting a pc to request the data im looking for for anything connected to that switch? or do you have any idea why the switches in question aren't counting traffic like they should ?

Comment: Just to be clear - your root desire is to have some good network statistics, correct? With that assumption are all interfaces on the switch in question showing empty counters or is it just this interface? What about the other switches in the stack? Have you tried different versions of firmware in that switch to see if the bug can be fixed with a software change?